# powerTutor, Android application battery consumption measurement

Tags: android, battery

For my study I need to measure the bettery power consumption of my application. After searching, I found PowerTutor app. My question is: is using this app enough for measring the battery consumption? Or do I need more information?

Thank you

Comment: @jimmym715 my post has nothing to do with power-management. It is about consumption and measurement of battery power. So please don't change the tags!

Comment: just acting based on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012